# Typeorm RepositoryNotFoundError in standalone expo app on Android

Tags: react-native, expo, typeorm

My app is running into this error when i try to log in and save some of the users info to the localdb.

this shows up in the logcat output

```
E unknown:ReactNative: RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Account" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
```

Here's some code importing the entities. When looking up the issue I found other people ran into this error because their imports were messed up but I'm pretty certain this is fine. I checked the promise for the connect function is returning fine before I try to get the repository.

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm/browser';
import * as ExpoSQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

import Account from './entities/AccountSchema';

class LocalDatabase {
  constructor() {
    this.connection = null;
  }

  async connect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      createConnection({
        database: 'local.db',
        driver: ExpoSQLite,
        entities: [
          Account,
        ],
        synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        type: 'expo',
        logging: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
      }).then((connection) => {
        this.connection = connection;
        resolve(connection);
      }).catch((err) => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

Ive tried setting synchronize to true to see if it does anything to fix it but the error still shows up.

Here's the entity file

```
import { EntitySchema } from 'typeorm';

import { Account } from '../models/Account';

const AccountSchema = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Account',
  target: Account,
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: 'varchar',
    },
    password: {
      type: 'varchar',
    },
    checklist: {
      type: 'varchar', // json
      transformer: {
        from(str) {
          return JSON.parse(str);
        },
        to(obj) {
          return JSON.stringify(obj);
        },
      },
    },
   ...
   ...
  },
});

export default AccountSchema;
```